# Поиск максимального по модулю элемента

Tags: c++

Какой алгоритм из стандартной библиотеки C++ можно использовать, чтобы вычислить модуль максимального по модулю элемента из заданного набора?

Answer (score 5):

`max_element`, вестимо. Со своим компаратором.

```
using namespace std;

int a[] = { -5, 2, 3, 8, -10, 6, 7, 4 };

auto x = max_element(begin(a),end(a),[](int a, int b) { return abs(a) < abs(b); });

cout << abs(*x) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей задачи могут подойти два стандартных алгоритма, оба которых объявлены в заголовочном файле `<algorithm>`. Это алгоритм `std::max`, который в качестве аргумента принимает объект типа `std::initializer_list`. Он имеет следующее объявление

```
template<class T, class Compare> 
constexpr T max(initializer_list<T> t, Compare comp);
```

Этот алгоритм возвращает максимальное значение.

И второй алгоритм - это алгоритм `std::max_element`, который в качестве аргументов принимает итераторы и возвращает итератор, указывающий на элемент с максимальным значением согласно заданному условию сравнения элементов.
Этот алгоритм имеет следующее объявление.

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class Compare> 
ForwardIterator max_element(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Compare comp);
```

Когда вы хотите найти максимальный элемент или максимальное значение элементов по абсолютной величине, то возникает одна проблема, о которой многие программисты забывают. Дело в том, что для чисел которые имеют представление дополнение до 2, как это имеет место у большинства компиляторов, если применить функцию, например, к объекту типа `int`, который имеет минимальное отрицательное значение, то функция `std::abs` вернет отрицательное значение! И естественно это отрицательное значение будет меньше любого положительного значения или нуля, хотя с математической точки зрения абсолютное значение этого минимального отрицательного значения должны быть по крайней мере больше 0.

Рассмотрите следующий простой пример.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    std::cout << "min = " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max = " << max << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::abs( min ) < 0 is "
              << std::boolalpha
              << (std::abs(min) < 0)
              << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль будет следующим

```
min = -2147483648
max = 2147483647
std::abs( min ) < 0 is true
```

Как видите, оказалось, что `std::abs( min )` меньше нуля, хотя с математической точки зрения очевидно, что значение `-2147483648` по абсолютной величине не только больше 0, но даже и больше максимального значения `2147483647`, которое может храниться в объектах типа `int`. Поэтому для последовательностей с целочисленными значениями применение стандартной функции `std::abs` может привести к неверном результату.

Как выйти из этого положения? Для целочисленных значений лучше сравнивать два значения, как отрицательные значения. Например, рассмотрим использование алгоритма `std::max`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    auto max_abs1 = [](int x, int y)
    {
        return std::abs(x) < std::abs(y);
    };

    int maximum = std::max({ std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
                             std::numeric_limits<int>::max() },
                             max_abs1);

    std::cout << "maximum = " << maximum << std::endl;

    auto max_abs2 = [](int x, int y)
    {
        return (y < 0 ? y : -y) < (x < 0 ? x : -x);
    };

    maximum = std::max({ std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        std::numeric_limits<int>::max() },
        max_abs2);

    std::cout << "maximum = " << maximum << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод этой программы следующий

```
maximum = 2147483647
maximum = -2147483648
```

Как видно из вывода, если применять стандартную функцию `std::abs`, то в качестве максимального значения по абсолютной величине будет значение `2147483647`. А если сравнивать числа как отрицательные числа, то максимальным по абсолютной величине будет значение `-2147483648`

Для наглядности просто замените в программе объявление типа переменной `maximum` с `int` на `unsigned int`

```
unsigned int maximum = std::max({ std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
                                 std::numeric_limits<int>::max() },
                                 max_abs1);
```

И вы для программы получите следующий результат

```
maximum = 2147483647
maximum = 2147483648
```

Из вывода видно, что первое значение, полученное после применения стандартной функции `std::abs` дает неверный результат.

Для чисел с плавающей запятой достаточно применять стандартную функцию `std::abs`.

Когда последовательность чисел задается не с помощью объекта `std::initializer_list`, то можно применить алгоритм `std::max_element`. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int a[] =
    {
        std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
    };

    auto max_abs = [](int x, int y)
    {
        return (y < 0 ? y : -y) < (x < 0 ? x : -x);
    };

    int *maximum = std::max_element(std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), max_abs);

    std::cout << "maximum = " << ( unsigned int )*maximum << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль будет, как и предполагалось, следующим

```
maximum = 2147483648
```

Comment: Непонятно получается. В вопросе спрашивают, как найти модуль максимального по модулю, но ведь если вы найдете это -2147483648, то его модуль уже не поместится в int - ну, о чем вы и пишете. Но тогда как минимум теряется вся переносимость? Так что вопрос в общем силучае просто не имеет смысла?\

Comment: @Mikhailo Я думаю, что просто коряво сформулирован вопрос. Скорей всего надо найти в последовательности элемент, абсолютная величина которого максимальна. Я показал, как можно это сделать. Если нужно вывести результат как неотрицательное число, то его нужно привести к беззнаковому типу.